# Responsive margin in css

Tags: html, css

I made some website that similiar with Youtube for study.

When decrease browser's size in youtube main, It's left and right margin is also decrease.

Is there any CSS trick for it?

Maybe I have to use margin: auto, But I don't know exactly what I have to do.

My layout is here ->

```
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="section">
      123
   </div>
</div>
```

wrap's height and width is 100% and section has `margin-left: 75px;`, `margin-right: 75px;`

Thanks.

Comment: would be better if you include your styling also, why not have a look at viewport units, or media queries.

Comment: You should set a width to .section (either px or %) and then margin: 0 auto; to .section

Comment: What happens *if* you use `margin: auto;` ?

Comment: What Jonas said is right: Don't use px if it should be scalable. So just use a %. You can also use media queries when it's getting to big/small because of the percentage. Then you can put there the new "rules" from a certain width.

Answer (score 0):

`margin: 0 auto;` is the way to go:

```css
.wrap {
width: 100%;
background: red;
}

.section {
width: calc(100% - 150px);
margin: 0 auto;
height: 100vh;
background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="section">
      123
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I mean that if decrease browser's size, .section's left and right margin is also decrease.

Comment: @Hide so use some "%" value instead of 150px

Answer (score -1):

```css
.wrap {
width: 100%;
background: #bababa;
}

.section {
width: calc(100% - 75px);
margin: 0 auto;
height: 100vh;
background: #7b7b7b;
color:#fff;
font-size:18px;
text-align:center;
line-height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="section">123</div>
</div>
```